# Customized startup page option for Phonegap Corodva app iOS (setting self.viewController.startPage="index.html" conditional)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

I have phonegap app developed for iOS, and I want to set startPage on specific condition, else app should load different another page as startup page.

I am new to Objective C, and have no idea about this method in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
//code
}
```

Is there any plugin or code available to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Statement:

My app has two options:

1. demo
2. customer

The default page shows the above two options,and if user selects the customer then app should automatically skip default page when starting the app next time(i.e user will be redirected to the home page for customer).

Solution is:

**Fake URL**

1. When user selects one of the two options then app hits the fake url:

> window.location.href="myfakeurl.html**demo**params"

with parameters appended to this url as: customer or demo (seperated by **)

1. In MainViewController.m

add following method that handles the url hit:

> -(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
>   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
>
> ```
>  NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];
>  NSArray *myarray=[[NSArray alloc]init];
>
>  if(url.length > 0)
>  {
>       NSLog(@"%@",url);
>       if ([url hasPrefix:@"myfakeurl"])
>       {
>
>            myarray=[url componentsSeparatedByString:@"**"];
>            NSString *params=[myarray objectAtIndex:1];
>
>            NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"www"];
>            path = [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>            NSString *str = @"//";
>
>            path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:%@%@/homepage.html%@",str,path,params];
>            NSURLRequest *newRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]] ;
>
>            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isCustomer"];
>            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
>            [theWebView loadRequest:newRequest];
>
>
>            return NO;
>
>       }
>
>  }    return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType]; }
> ```

1. Now in AppDelegate.m

check for the key in nsuserdefaults and appropriately set the startup page as shown below:

> -(BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
>       //other code
>
> //...
>
> ```
>  self.viewController.startPage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isCustomer"] ? @"homepage.html" :
> ```
>
> @"default.html";
>         //......
>
> ```
> return YES; }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript and check your conditions inside DeviceReady event and change the pages

Answer (score -1):

Its right there in the method itself, if you take a close look in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{    
    NSURL* url = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    if (url && [url isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
      self.invokeString = [url absoluteString];
      NSLog(@"TestAnother launchOptions = %@", url);
    }    

CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

CGRect viewBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
self.viewController.startPage = @"index2.html";
self.viewController.view.frame = viewBounds;

.
.
.
.


    return YES;
}
```

You can check condition and set     `self.viewController.startPage = @"index2.html";`

Comment: Hi Deepesh, I think u misunderstood my question.I want to call javascript method in the above function and want to check if condition is satisifed.The javascript code will return true or false and I want to set start page as index1 or index.html accordingly.